# Extracting files from NanoZip archive

Tags: linux, compression

I have compressed some files with [NanoZip](http://www.nanozip.net) on Linux with:

```
./nz c a -cc file.nz files/*
```

Now I'm trying to extract them with

```
./nz x file.nz file_copy/*
```

but I can't find the output. The same goes for

```
./nz x file.nz -o file_copy/*
```

It says that I have extracted everything, and it takes a long time to do that. I just can't find the extracted files.

Comment: Offtopic. I would not consider a file compressor a tool related to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./nz c a -cc file.nz files/*
Unknown command c
```

I assume you actually did something like

```
./nz a -cc file.nz files/*
```

to compress the files

To unpack, your line should be

```
./nz x -ofile_copy file.nz
```

Note the lack of space between `-o` and its argument (run `nz` without arguments to see the syntax). You should also just define a single output directory argument; the `*` in your `-o file_copy/*` is expanded by the shell to

- nothing if the `file_copy` dir does not exist or is empty, and to
- the files currently in the `file_copy` dir if it is not empty.

On my system, the binary just segfaults though, so I can't try it "for real".